# Exclude string from preg_match_all if string contains certain value

Tags: php, magento2, preg-match-all

Im using `preg_match_all` to grab all scripts and place bfore body end like below:

```
preg_match_all('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', $html, $matches);
$js = '';
foreach ($matches[0] as $value):
    $js .= $value;
endforeach;
$html = preg_replace('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('#</body>#',$js.'</body>',$html);
```

This has broken some functionality on the page however for a few scripts like below:

```
<script data-template="bundle-summary" type="text/x-magento-template">
      <li>
            <strong class="label"><%- data._label_ %>:</strong>
            <div data-container="options"></div>
      </li>
</script>
```

How can i use the `preg_match_all` to exclude `<script data-template` scripts from being moved.

I  figured i could check if the script `x-magento-template` script by doing something like below:

```
if (strpos($value, 'type="text/x-magento-template"') === false) {
    $js .= $value;
}
```

Then it won't be added to the `$js` variable however am unsure how to stop the same scripts being deleted in the below line:

```
$html = preg_replace('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', '', $html);
```

I need to replace all scripts however not if they contain `type="text/x-magento-template`

**Update**

I did the below but am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this with preg_match_all?

```
            preg_match_all('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', $html, $matches);
            $js = '';
            foreach ($matches[0] as $value):
                if (strpos($value, 'type="text/x-magento-template"') === false) {
                    $js .= $value;
                    $html = str_replace($value, '', $html);
                }
            endforeach;
            //$html = preg_replace('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', '', $html);
            $html = preg_replace('#</body>#',$js.'</body>',$html);
```

After timing the difference between the method with the if statment and not the differences were negligible with a time of about 0.005 seconds each so am happy to leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For html editing, a DOM approach gives better results:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html); // or $dom->loadHTMLFile('./file.html'); 

$removeList=[];
$bodyNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $scriptNode) {
    if ( $scriptNode->hasAttribute('type') && $scriptNode->getAttribute('type')=='text/x-magento-template' )
        continue;

    $removeList[] = $scriptNode;
}

foreach ($removeList as $scriptNode) {
    $bodyNode->appendChild($scriptNode);
}

libxml_use_internal_errors($state);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

With this code you don't have to delete script nodes since they move from their current position in dom tree to the end of the body element (since they are appended).

Comment: Thanks this looks nice i will give it a go.

Comment: @harri : You can do it without using a fragment, I will edit my post.

Comment: As nice as it looks it seems to take 10 times longer. 0.005 vs 0.05

Comment: @harri: there's no point to time this kind of script (in particular to compare it with a script that doesn't work). If you project to run this script each time a page is called, you have a big design problem in your application. What you are trying to do must be done once and for all.

Comment: My way works fine tho its not that it doesnt work. And i know this isnt gonna call each time but across 20,000 pages on a cache warming script will shave me 15 mins or so off so will still keep my method.

Comment: Thanks for your help tho i will probably refer to this in future and mark as answer.

Comment: @harri: you can speed-up the ugly regex approach doing that: `$matches = '';$html = preg_replace_callback('~(<script\b[^t>]*+(?:\Bt+[^t>]*|t(?!ype="text/x-magento-template")[^t>]*)*+>[^<]*+(?:<(?!/script>)[^<]*+)*+</script>)\s*~i', function ($m) use (&$matches) { $matches.=$m[1]; }, $html);$html = str_ireplace('</body>', $matches.'</body>', $html);`. But it's less flexible and more error prone than a DOM approach.

Comment: Awesome that's some nice regex. Yeah i think if i was making this as a module for multiple others to use i would take the less error prone DOM approach. As this is just for myself i'm going to take the faster approach as i know i wont run into problems in my current context and every 15 min counts when trying to get this cache to warm up during the night.